# Как задать несколько методов на один эндпоинт в django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

У меня есть 2 класса для GET и PATCH запросов

*views.py*

```
class ResumeAPIList(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Resume.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ResumeSerializer


class ResumeAPIUpdate(UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Resume.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ResumeSerializer
```

И я хочу, чтобы на один и тот же эндпоинт в зависимости от метода вызывался один из двух этих классов

*urls.py*

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('resume/<int:pk>/', ResumeAPIList.as_view()),
    path('resume/<int:pk>/', ResumeAPIUpdate.as_view())
]
```

Если я делаю так, как описал выше, то GET запрос отрабатывает нормально, а PATCH уходит с ошибкой:

```
Method Not Allowed: /resume/1/
```

Как это можно решить?

Comment: используйте `ViewSet`